# Where does the expectation term in the derivative of the soft-max policy come from?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, math, policies, expectation

[At slide 17](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Silver/web/Teaching_files/pg.pdf) of the David Silver's series, the soft-max policy is defined as follows

$$
\pi_\theta(s, a) \propto e^{\phi(s, a)^T \theta}
$$

that is, the probability of an action $a$ (in state $s$) is proportional to the "exponentiated weight".

The score function is then defined as follows

$$
\nabla_\theta \log \pi_\theta (s, a) = \phi(s, a) - 
\mathbb{E}_{\pi_{\theta}}[\phi(s, \cdot)]
$$

Where does the expectation term $\mathbb{E}_{\pi_{\theta}}[\phi(s, \cdot)]$ come from?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but I'll try to answer it anyway.
The expectation term comes from the derivative of the softmax function. This video from Geoffrey Hinton should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlaLLQofmR8

Comment: The confusion here is that, when we take log of pi, then it will log(sum x_i) in dem, where x_i is that expression. Now my doubt is here this term log(sum_i  x_i) is replace by sum_i (log x_i), how? Is this inequality valid?

Comment: see this answer over on the math.stackexchange.com site: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2340848/414001